# JavaScript: reduce and map

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to understand why the author of this function would call reduce on an object that is already the result of a call to map.  This is a render function from a backbone app (demo here http://fire-camp.heroku.com/ ). The variable "messages" represents a collection of the messages the users enter into the messaging system. Why would the author call map and then reduce on the results of map i.e. 'data.' I don't understand how reduce adds anything new to the data variable. Let me know if you need more information.

```
render: function() {
    var data = messages.map(function(message) { return message.get('content') + 'n'});
    var result = data.reduce(function(memo,str) { return memo + str }, '');
    $("#chatHistory").text(result);
    return this;
  }
```

Full source code for the very short app is here but I don't think you'll need it. https://github.com/ryandotsmith/fire-camp

Comment: The "map" function returns an array; "reduce" collapses that array into a scalar. That said, the author of the code should probably have used `.join()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, in the hopes of getting a fuller answer from someone, comment by @pointy only partially answers the question. Doesn't really explain the "why" part. For example, in the app, if I insert the data variable into text(data), it still works the same, so why need reduce? or join for that matter?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. it doesn't work if i pass the array to text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pointy mentioned, the reason the author has used `reduce`
is to concatenate the array into a single string (or reducing
it to a string). As @Pointy also mentions, though, the rationale
for using `reduce` is not very good in this case.

Given the code on GitHub there are several alternatives that
are better. Considering that the code uses Backbone.js and that
the `messages` variable points to a `Backbone.Collection` this
code would be more clear if it read something along the lines
of this:

```
render: function() {
  var result = messages.pluck('content').join('\n')
  $("#chatHistory").text(result);
  return this;
}
```

Using `reduce` for joining an array of strings is overkill and
obscures the intention of the code. Using `map` together with
`Backbone.Collection` just to pluck out a particular attribute
from the models inside also somewhat obscures the intention
of the code.